# Postgres join query: Most efficient

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a application where users can take images and tag them selfs. Here is the database structure looks like:

For the purpose of this problem lets take three main table that involve:

user, image, user_image

```
user table
id, user_name, age
1, test1, 23
2, test2, 34

image table
id, users_in_image, datetime
1, test1,test2, 03/01/2000
2, test1, 03/01/2003

user_image table
id, user_id, image_id
1, 1, 1
2, 1, 2
```

Every time user take an image it creates a record in image, user and user_image, given a user I want to see all users that user has taken images with and what are those image_ids.

Here is my solution

```
select * from user_image where image_id
in (select image_id from user_image where user_id = '1') and user_id != '1';
```

I am worried this is not a good solution. I would like to get some thoughts from experts.

Comment: In the image table the users_in_image field is an array?

Comment: Nope unfortunately not its a comma seperated text db was design like that.

Comment: Find whoever designed it and whack them with a cluebat. Gently.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? Show example results. etc.

Comment: Your question should probably not be title "most efficient" since you don't even have a solution, at all, yet.

Comment: @DwayneTowell I added my solution sorry about that.

Comment: What causes you to worry? Have you tried it and had poor performance? If possible, my first port of call would be to try it out on a realistic dataset, rather that premature optimization. If you can't get your hands on a realistic dataset, say that because otherwise people are likely to just downvote you for not asking a real question.

Comment: I tried my solution at the moment database has less than 1000 records so "in queries" sometime end up becoming performance issues thats the reason I asked a better solution. Not sure if you saw my solution. Also wondering if the negative can be taken off.

Comment: Most probably unrelated, but: don't compare apples (numbers) to oranges (strings). `1` is a number `'1'` is a character string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually mean:

*"Find all users that are connected to an image that a given user is connected to"*

```
SELECT ui2.user_id
FROM   user_image ui1
JOIN   user_image ui2 USING (image_id)
WHERE  ui1.user_id =  1
AND    ui2.user_id <> 1
GROUP  BY 1;
```

Join the table to its self.
Or, to get actual users, not just `user_id`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM  (
   SELECT ui2.user_id
   FROM   user_image ui1
   JOIN   user_image ui2 USING (image_id)
   WHERE  ui1.user_id =  1
   AND    ui2.user_id <> 1
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) ui
JOIN  "user" u ON u.id = ui.user_id;
```

Why the quotes around `'1'`? You are not storing numbers as text, are you?

Aside: Don't use the reserved word `user` as identifier.

Comment: What I am trying to do is Given a user, who are the other users this user has taken images with.

Comment: but why would we use `AND ui2.user_id <> 2` to the query only one userId should be passed in. Assume from web point of few user login 1 login...

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis: Sorry, that was a typo.